# Android ArrayList with 4 params

Tags: java, android

I'm creating own List with 4 parameters.
I have an example with standard list with 2 parameters.
How can I declare ArrayList for 4 parameters and not 2?

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = buildData();
String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };
int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956844/hashmap-with-multiple-values-under-the-same-key what you want is a hashmap with four values not a arraylist with 4 parameters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that contains four parameters. for example:

```
public class MyClass {

    public String param1;

    public String param2;

    public String param3;

    public String param4;
}
```

Then, declare your arraylist as:

```
ArrayList< MyClass > list = buildData();

String[] from = { "name", "purpose", .... };

    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, ... };
```

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of Map will be appropriate here.

```
public class SomeClass{

    public String str1;

    public String str2;

    public String str3;

    public String str4;


}


ArrayList<SomeClass, HashMap<String, String>> map = newArrayList<SomeClass,HashMap<String, String>>();
```