# Store multiple values (of different types) under a same key using 'Map' in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to instantiate a map structure with the following

```
Map<Timestamp, Test> map = new Map<Timestamp, Test>();
```

where Test is a class with 3 different types of variables and Timestamp is a java.sql.Timestamp type.

But I am getting the following error

> Can not instantiate type `Map<Timestamp, Test>`

My primary objective is to create a map structure where I can store multiple values/objects (of different types) from a Class implementation under the same timestamp key.

Comment: To store multiple values within a key you can refer to [HashMap with multiple values under the same key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956844/hashmap-with-multiple-values-under-the-same-key)

Comment: [Java Tutorials: The Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `Map<Timestamp, Test>`

   You can't instantiate Map because it is interface. You need to do use one of the implementations like `HashMap`.
2. You can't store multiple values in HashMap, for same Key unless values are either collection of objects (or) array. Another alternative is [Google MultiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: using HashMap now I am getting the following error:
`HashMap cannot be resolved to a type`
any suggestion, pls?

Comment: @JoarderKamal:Make sure imports are there.

Comment: Just wondering, how can I now put multiple values using the Test class variables (I have 3 variables of different types in Test). Any guidance kindly?

Comment: @JoarderKamal: I would suggest to add all 3 instances of Test to either ArrayList (or) HashSet etc., and add this collection to your map.

Answer (score 3):

YOu can't instantiate an Interface.

Use HashMap on the righthand side

Answer (score 3):

`Map` is an `interface`. You cannot instantiate an `interface`.

You need to use a class that implements the `Map` interface. Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
Map<Timestamp, Test> map = new HashMap<Timestamp, Test>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
Map<Timestamp, Test> map = new HashMap<Timestamp, Test>();
```

instead of

```
Map<Timestamp, Test> map = new Map<Timestamp, Test>();
```

as you cannot instantiate the interface Map

The other thing you have mentioned that you want to store the values of different types, so use Object as the value instead of Test:

> `Map<Timestamp, Object> map = new HashMap<Timestamp, Object>();`

Comment: Thanks for the guide. No more error message now.
Btw, I actually wanted to use multiple values of different types not a single Object (of different type).