# What is the reason why this code is not working?

Tags: java

I have a class like this:

```
public class StringCheckLHMapSorted<K, V>
    extends
    ObjectLHMapSorted<K, V> {
```

I have a LinkedHashMap inside declared as follows:

```
private final Map<Integer, StringCheck> scoLHMap =
        (Map<Integer, StringCheck>) new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
```

The class StringCheck has this attributes with its respective setters/getters and nothing else inside:

```
private boolean check;
private String string;
```

I created a method inside the class described at the top of this question like this:

```
public LinkedHashMap<Boolean, String> getSCLHAllStringAndCheckInside() {
LinkedHashMap<Boolean, String> allStrCh = new LinkedHashMap<Boolean, String>();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, StringCheck> e : scoLHMap.entrySet()) {
        allStrCh.put(e.getValue().isCheck(), e.getValue().getString());
}

    return allStrCh;
}
```

The object returned allStrCh gives me only one entry; the last one inserted to be more specific. I've replaced allStrCh with an ArrayList to get only keys/values and it gives me the complete list of each one of them; keys/values.

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why doesn't your backing map use the bounds `K` and `V` instead of `Integer` and `StringCheck`?

Comment: Well you've got a map from `Boolean` to `String` - there are only two `Boolean` values (false and true) so your map *can* only contain two entries. If it's only got one entry, then presumably `isCheck()` was false for all entries, or it was true for all entries.

Comment: Makoto, ObjectLHMapSorted<K, V> expects a more wider range of keys/values.

Comment: Jon Skeet, scoLHMap holds <Integer, StringCheck>, so, I want a list like this: --Name : 3loagt, Status: true-- for every key in scoLHMap

Comment: You were right Jon Skeet. I used them in the reverse way. String to Boolean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedHashMap just preserves the order of insertion - if you .put(true,x) and then .put(true,y) it will still overwrite whatever was at the true key previously.

You probably want to do something like this? [HashMap with multiple values under the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956844/hashmap-with-multiple-values-under-the-same-key)

Comment: I get it. I can not have duplicates. So you recommend me use them in the reverse way. I mean <String, Boolean>. The strings are 6 random characters.