# How can I foreach a hashmap?

Tags: android, loops, hashmap

I have a hashmap with the values :

```
1 - 18;
1 - 19;
1 - 20;
3 - 21;
3 - 22;
8 - 23;
8 -24;
8 - 25;
11 - 26;
```

And I gotta loop it and check whether the key is equal the specific value, which will be a parameter. So, let's say my parameter is the number 3. It should return this to me:

```
21, 22.
```

Thanks!

Comment: In Map key cant be duplicate.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: What you have mentioned is not an HashMap. HashMap cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: Should I use an arraylist or what then, to store multiple keys (ID) and value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HashMap with multiple values under the same key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956844/hashmap-with-multiple-values-under-the-same-key)

Comment: I'm not sure how I could adapt the duplicated question to my issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = ...;

for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
    // do something
}
```

Or

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = entries.next();
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

EDIT: According to your comment this is what you need, just paste this somewhere and observe and play with it a bit, I tryied to comment the imporant sutff

```
private void hashMapTest() {
    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> testMap = new HashMap<>();
    int i; // Iterator

    // ArrayLists that hold the integer values at specific key
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>();

    // Fill the lists with some demo data.
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        list1.add(i);
    }

    for (; i < 10; ++i) {
        list2.add(i);
    }

    for (; i < 15; ++i) {
        list3.add(i);
    }

    for (; i < 20; ++i) {
        list4.add(i);
    }

    // Add the data holders to the map. Note the keys in HashMap must be unique!!
    testMap.put(1, list1);
    testMap.put(2, list2);
    testMap.put(3, list3);
    testMap.put(4, list4);

    // Let's you want to get the values with the key 3 amd print it out
    for (Integer integer : testMap.get(3)) {
        Log.d("loop test", "Integer: " + integer);
    }

    // Now let's say you want to add some value to one of the lists, say key 2
    testMap.get(2).add(12314151);
    testMap.get(2).add(1231);
    testMap.get(2).add(77565);

    // And print it
    for (Integer integer : testMap.get(2)) {
        Log.d("loop test2", "Integer: " + integer);
    }

}
```

Will produce something like this

```
05-22 21:34:35.765  20092-20092/? D/loop test﹕ Integer: 10
05-22 21:34:35.765  20092-20092/? D/loop test﹕ Integer: 11
05-22 21:34:35.765  20092-20092/? D/loop test﹕ Integer: 12
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test﹕ Integer: 13
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test﹕ Integer: 14
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test2﹕ Integer: 5
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test2﹕ Integer: 6
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test2﹕ Integer: 7
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test2﹕ Integer: 8
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test2﹕ Integer: 9
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test2﹕ Integer: 12314151
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test2﹕ Integer: 1231
05-22 21:34:35.766  20092-20092/? D/loop test2﹕ Integer: 77565
```

Comment: Hello! THank you very much for your time, but this sample doesn't fix my problem, unfortunately. I need to pass a number via parameter and it should return me all values which are equal to that number

Comment: Equal to key or the value?

Comment: Equal to key! For instance, my hashmap contains the following (key and value respectively)
_3 - 5
3 - 6 
1 - 7_ ~ so,  if I ask for the value 3, it should return the 5 and 6. I should use a <Integer, List<Integer>> map, right? But how could I add and retrieve the values?

Comment: I will show you later if nobody else will do it sooner, got dinner.

Comment: are you back from dinner?

Comment: Yes, I'm making a simple example for you. You will copy paste it to your activity and all will be clear

Comment: @HenryStuart I have made a simple test function for you