# HashMap<Key,List<Object>> from list of objects containing same property

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap

I have a List of objects.

eg>

### Object 1

groupId=1
name=name1

### Object 2

groupId=1
name=name2

### Object 3

groupId=1
name=name3

### Object 4

groupId=2
name=name4

Multiple objects in the List have same value for `groupId`. I need to create Sub-Lists of objects with same `groupId`. How do I do this in Java.

My Inital thought was to create a `HashMap<Integer,List<Object>>` but i am unsure about indefinite values of `groupIds` coming in , which in turn makes me unsure about  how to group objects with same `groupIds` together with `groupId` as the hashmap's key.

If the groupId's were not to change or increase in the future i could have iterated over the original list and written a switch statement to create required arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it this way. I used `LinkedHashMap<K,V>` as i had to preserve the order of my objects i had sorted according to object's priority value property.

```
    LinkedHashMap<Group, List<Object>> hashMap=new LinkedHashMap<Group, List<Object>>();        

    for(Object model:objects){

            if(!hashMap.containsKey(model.getGroup())){
            List<Object> list= new ArrayList<Object>();
            list.add(model);
            hashMap.put(Group,list);
        }
        else{
            hashMap.get(model.getGroup()).add(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

With Java 8 you could use [the `groupingBy` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> map = list.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getGroupId));
```

Comment: I need this for android so java 8 isn't an option. great solution though thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In **Java 8** you can use some filters.

```
public class A {
    public int groupId;
    public String name;

    public A(int groupId, String name) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Filter using Collections API

```
ArrayList<A> list=new ArrayList();
list.add(new A(2, "tom"));
list.add(new A(2, "rome"));
list.add(new A(1, "sam"));

List<A> filteredlist = list.stream().filter(p -> p.groupId==2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a Map like this -

```
Map map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

Where the `key` in the `HashMap` is `Integer` represents your `groupId` (ie. - 1, 2, 3 etc) and `value` (ie - name1, name2 etc) of the `HashMap` stored at the `List` of `String`.

You may use the following steps -

**1.** Iterate over your four lists.
**2.** Add each item to a `Map` construction (eg.- here `map`) based on the key groupId.

I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956844/hashmap-with-multiple-values-under-the-same-key) would be helpful in this context.

Comment: That was the first thing i thought but I am unsure about the number of groups coming in from the datasource. if i was certain about group count it wouldn't be an issue.