# java: print size of each ArrayList in a map<enumType, List<object>

Tags: java

I have the following map:

```
Map<InputTypeEnum, List<Object>> objectsMap; 
objectsMap.put(InputTypeEnum.Text, textList);
objectsMap.put(InputTypeEnum.Number, NumbersList);
objectsMap.put(InputTypeEnum.Symbols, SymbolsList);
```

I want to iterate through the Map and print to console the number of objects in list per InputTypeEnum.

for example:

> "the text list has 4 elements"
>
> "the numbers list has 2 elements"
>
> "the symbols list has 5 elements"

I couldn't find any example here, or in google.

thanks for the help!

Comment: `for (InputTypeEnum key : objectsMap.keySet()) System.out.println(key.toString()+", "+objectMap.get(key).size()); ` (This works only when you have a String-value and a toString()-method for every element in your enum)

Comment: thanks man! that's really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want something exactly like you said you don't really need iteration, only get from map those values:

```
System.out.printf("the text list has %d elements \n",objectsMap.get(InputTypeEnum.Text).size());
    System.out.printf("the numbers list has %d elements \n",objectsMap.get(InputTypeEnum.Number).size());
    System.out.printf("the symbols list has %d elements",objectsMap.get(InputTypeEnum.Symbols).size());
```

But if when you said "iterate" this is because you have more than one list of each tipe in your map. In that case you should consider another approach, this one you replace your old value under the same key. You can see that in my example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

enum InputTypeEnum{
    Text, Number, Symbols;
}

public class MapEnumIteration {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List textList = new ArrayList<String>();
        textList.add("test1");
        textList.add("test2");
        textList.add("test3");
        textList.add("test4");

        List numbersList = new ArrayList<Number>();
        numbersList.add(1);
        numbersList.add(2);

        List symbolsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        symbolsList.add("symbol1");
        symbolsList.add("symbol2");
        symbolsList.add("symbol3");
        symbolsList.add("symbol4");
        symbolsList.add("symbol5");


        List textList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        textList2.add("test 2.1");
        textList2.add("test 2.2");

    Map<InputTypeEnum, List<Object>> objectsMap = new HashMap<InputTypeEnum, List<Object>>(); 
    objectsMap.put(InputTypeEnum.Text, textList);
    objectsMap.put(InputTypeEnum.Number, numbersList);
    objectsMap.put(InputTypeEnum.Symbols, symbolsList);

    objectsMap.put(InputTypeEnum.Text, textList2);

    System.out.printf("the text list has %d elements \n",objectsMap.get(InputTypeEnum.Text).size());
    System.out.printf("the numbers list has %d elements \n",objectsMap.get(InputTypeEnum.Number).size());
    System.out.printf("the symbols list has %d elements",objectsMap.get(InputTypeEnum.Symbols).size());



    }

}
```

> {Symbols=[symbol1, symbol2, symbol3, symbol4, symbol5], Text=[test
>   2.1, test 2.2], Number=[1, 2]}

I hope you find this useful too:

[HashMap with multiple values under the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956844/hashmap-with-multiple-values-under-the-same-key)