# How java HashMap does chaining? how to access all collision values?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I have read somewhere that HashMap uses chaining to resolve collisions. But if that is the case. how can i access all the elements with same key value.

For example :

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
hmap.put(1, "1st value");
hmap.put(1, "2nd value");
hmap.put(1, "3rd value");
hmap.put(1, "4th value");
```

Now, if I do hmap.get(1) it returns “4th Value”

if Indeed it does chaining like

> Key           values 1            “4th Value” ---> “3rd Value”--->”2nd Value”---->
>   “1st Value”

How can I get the other values?

`hmap.get(1)` only returns the 1st value.

My second question is,

if it does linear chaining. How can I remove any one value for a key. suppose I want to remove “4th value” from my hashmap and want to keep all other values for same key, how can i do it?

if I do

> hmap.remove(1);

, it removes the complete chain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`HashMap` cannot store multiple values for the same key.

[Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) is used to resolve hash collisions, i.e. situations when different keys have the same hash. So, it's not about storing multiple values with the same key, it's about multiple values whose keys have the same hashes.

Data structure that can store multiple values for the same key is called a multimap. Unfortunately, there is no built-in implementation of multimap in JRE.

If you need a multimap, you can maintain a `Map` of `List`s (as suggested by matsev), or use an existing multimap implementation from a third-party library, such as [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

**See also:**

- [Collision resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

Comment: Or to put it another way, a collision occurs when two *different* keys hash to the same hash table slot.  What the OP is multiple keys that are the same.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [HashMap.put(K, V)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

What you can do is to put a `List` as your *value*, e.g.

```
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
List<String> list = hmap.get(1);
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    hmap.put(1, list);
}
list.add("1st value");
list.add("2nd value");
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think HashTable allows duplicate keys. You should read this [What happens when a duplicate key is put into a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669885/what-happens-when-a-duplicate-key-is-put-into-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously looking for a data structure like Guava's [MultiMap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) which allows exactly what you want: Having multiple values per key.

Java's HashMap does *not* do chaining, as the [documentation for `put(K, V)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) clearly states:

> public V put(K key, V value)
>
> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is
>   replaced.

Comment: Actually, it does do hash chaining.  But chaining is not about storing multiple copies of the same key in a map.  It is about dealing with the case where *different* keys map to the same slot in the hash table.  That's what a collision is.

Answer (score 0):

If you store an existing key in the HashMap then it will override the old value with the new value and put() will return the old value

```
      System.out.println(hmap.put("1",1st value));
      System.out.println(hmap);  // o/p "1st value"
```