# Need simple explanation how "lock striping" works with ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

According to Java Concurrency in Practice, chapter 11.4.3 says:

> Lock splitting can sometimes be extended to partition
>   locking on a variablesized set of independent objects, in which case
>   it is called lock striping. For example, the implementation of
>   ConcurrentHashMap uses an array of 16 locks, each of which guards 1/16
>   of the hash buckets; bucket N is guarded by lock N mod 16.

I still have problems to understand and visualize the lock striping and buckets mechanism.
Can someone explain this with good understanding words :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The hash map is built on an array, where the hash function maps an object to an element in the underlying array.  Let's say the underlying array has 1024 elements - ConcurrentHashMap actually turns this into 16 different sub-arrays of 64 elements, e.g. {0, 63}, {64, 127}, etc.  Each sub-array has its own lock, so modifying the {0, 63} sub-array doesn't impact the {64, 127} sub-array - one thread can write to the first sub-array while another thread writes to the second sub-array.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But what about if two or more threads are trying to modify all in sub-array {0,63}?

Comment: Then it's first come first served - the first thread to acquire the lock makes its changes, then when it finishes the second thread makes its changes.  `ConcurrentHashMap` has methods like `replace` to ensure that the second thread doesn't inadvertently overwrite the first thread's changes.

Comment: I don't think it's actually "first come first served," as I understand (I don't have the exact quote, but I learned it from Java Concurrency in Practice,) fairness is only guaranteed when it's explicit, like in constructors for the different explicit `Lock` implementations, such as `ReentrantLock`, or the Queues such as `ArrayBlockingQueue`.
(I know it's an old thread, sorry)

Comment: Had a very brief look at Java 8 implementation and I don't see any segment level arrays. I know that above answer is written before java 8. But can someone clarify now segments are nothing but individual buckets or row in the table ? Is the word lock striping obsolete since we don't do lock for stripe of rows ?

Answer (score 17):

The difference between locking in a `Collections.synchronizedMap()` and a `ConcurrentHashMap` is as follows:

If multiple threads will access a `Collections.synchronizedMap()` frequently, there will be a lot of contention since each method is synchronized using a shared lock (i.e. if thread X calls a method on a `Collections.synchronizedMap()`, all other threads will be blocked from calling any method on a `Collections.synchronizedMap()` until thread X returns from the method it called).

A `ConcurrentHashMap` has a variable number of locks (default is 16) that each guard a segment of the keys in the `ConcurrentHashMap`. So for a `ConcurrentHashMap` with 160 keys, each lock will guard 10 elements. Therefore, methods operating on a key (`get`, `put`, `set`, etc...) only lock out access to other methods operating on a key where the keys are in the same segment. For example, if thread X calls `put(0, someObject)`, and then thread Y calls `put(10, someOtherObject)` those calls can execute concurrently, and thread Y does not have to wait for thread X to return from `put(0, someObject)`. An example is provided below.

Additionally, certain methods such as `size()` and `isEmpty()` are not guarded at all. While this allows for greater concurrency, it means they are not strongly-consistent (they won't reflect state that is concurrently changing).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(160);

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      map.put(0, "guarded by one lock");
    }
  }.start();

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      map.put(10, "guarded by another lock");
    }
  }.start();

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // could print 0, 1, or 2
      System.out.println(map.count());
    }
  }.start();
}
```

Comment: HashMap in java is not thread safe, HashTable is. The first scenario you talk about is for HashTable

Answer (score 3):

The key concept here is the "bucket" . instead using a global lock for this whole hash Table, it uses one small lock for each bucket. 
It's also a good analogous to bucket sort which can improve sorting complexity.