# Why is weak_table_t a member of SideTable in Objective-C runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I am reading code of objc from https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4.

In the code, there is a struct SideTable, which contains reference count of corresponding object and a weak_table_t.

```
struct SideTable {
    spinlock_t slock;
    RefcountMap refcnts;
    weak_table_t weak_table;

    SideTable() {
        memset(&weak_table, 0, sizeof(weak_table));
    }

    ~SideTable() {
        _objc_fatal("Do not delete SideTable.");
    }

    void lock() { slock.lock(); }
    void unlock() { slock.unlock(); }
    bool trylock() { return slock.trylock(); }

    // Address-ordered lock discipline for a pair of side tables.

    template<bool HaveOld, bool HaveNew>
    static void lockTwo(SideTable *lock1, SideTable *lock2);
    template<bool HaveOld, bool HaveNew>
    static void unlockTwo(SideTable *lock1, SideTable *lock2);
};
```

And the SideTable of an object can be retrieved by SideTables()[obj] as the SideTable of every object is stored in a StripedMap, which is actually an array using the hash value of an object's address as index.

But according to the code of weak_entry_for_referent, the runtime gets the weak_entry_t of a referent through checking weak_table->weak_entries[index].referent.

```
static weak_entry_t *
weak_entry_for_referent(weak_table_t *weak_table, objc_object *referent)
{
    assert(referent);

    weak_entry_t *weak_entries = weak_table->weak_entries;

    if (!weak_entries) return nil;

    size_t index = hash_pointer(referent) & weak_table->mask;
    size_t hash_displacement = 0;
    while (weak_table->weak_entries[index].referent != referent) {
        index = (index+1) & weak_table->mask;
        hash_displacement++;
        if (hash_displacement > weak_table->max_hash_displacement) {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    return &weak_table->weak_entries[index];
}
```

It means the weak_table contains more than the weak entries for a single object. Then why is weak_table_t a member of SideTable instead of a global data?

As I can't find code which really initialize SideTable of object (storeStrong just use the SideTable without initializing it at first) and weak_table, I can't quite understand how things work in the background.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: I do not understand your conclusion: The weak table contains a list of every other object referring one specific object in account. The function returns the entry for the specific object in account and a referrer (referent). So each object holds a (local) table for its referrers.

Comment: According to my understanding, weak_entry_for_referent will return the entry in weak_table->weak_entries for a referent (the object referred by weak references). If the weak_table or weak_table->weak_entries in a SideTable contains only weak referrers for itself, why should we check if the referent is the referent we are looking for by "while (weak_table->weak_entries[index].referent != referent)"?

Comment: Because it takes an object reference (`objc_object`) and return the whole entry (`weak_entry_t`). So you can get the entry for a reference. `weak_entry_t` contains more information than `id` (aka `objc_object`).

Comment: to improve access speed.looks like that much people take the subway from many door at the same time

Answer (score 1):

## why is `weak_table_t` a member of SideTable

There are two cases should be solved if use a global `weak_table_t`.(`refcnts` has the same cases)

- case 1: Maintaining the `weak_table_t` should be thread safe, so we need lock
- case 2: lock means slow, but the developer want the system run as fast as possible

Only one global `weak_table_t` can't solved the two cases above.

Actuactly, `class StripedMap` solves the two cases by using `lock striping`, by wrapping `weak_table_t` and `refcnts` together inside `SideTable`.

Let's take a look at the code below, copied from `objc-private.h`.

```
// StripedMap<T> is a map of void* -> T, sized appropriately 
// for cache-friendly lock striping. 
// For example, this may be used as StripedMap<spinlock_t>
// or as StripedMap<SomeStruct> where SomeStruct stores a spin lock.
template<typename T>
class StripedMap {
    // ... code for StripedMap
    PaddedT array[StripeCount]; // There are 8 SideTables if define TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    // ... code for StripedMap
}
```

8 SideTables store 8 `weak_table_t` and 8 `spinlock_t slock`. The system can maintain 8 `weak_table_t` cocurrently at most for 8 thread.
I think this is fast enought on a iOS device.

## SideTable init

`SideTablesMap.init();` called from `arr_init()`.
You can use "Find Call Hierarchy" on `init` of `class ExplicitInit` to find the call hierarchy

Comment: More readings on Lock Striping: 
[Fine-grained locks on C++ map of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314607/)    
[Need simple explanation how "lock striping" works with ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151732/)

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable reason I can figure out is:

The SideTableBuf for all SideTable instances is actually a bucket array. Different objects may be put in the same bucket. So a single SideTable may serve for different pointers according to the hash algorithm. And then, the weak_table actually contains weak_entry_t for different referents. That's why we need check the referent by:

```
while (weak_table->weak_entries[index].referent != referent)
```

And the weak_table serves for the current SideTable only, so it can't be a global data.

Answer (score 0):

Weak table is a shared resource which allows access from multiple threads. Thus, we need a lock to avoid data inconsistency. So `weak_table_t` is wrapped in `SideTable` along with `spinlock_t`.

However, it's inefficient to have the whole table locked for each access. Considering the case, *Thread A* has acquired the lock, and is modifying the weak table. Meanwhile, *Thread B* wants to modify the weak table, so it tries to acquire the lock. However, only one thread can own the lock at a time. So *Thread B* blocks.  If this happens all the time, access to weak table would be very slow.

Then developers came up with the pattern, "Lock Striping", dividing the table into multiple buckets, each of which can be locked independently. Upon that modifying bucket 1 doesn't block the modifying of bucket 2. So `SideTable` is wrapped in `StripedMap` for partition purpose.