# How to print all the values for a key in HashMap in java

Tags: java, hashmap

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("1", "xyz");
map.put("1", "abc");
map.put("1", "cde");
map.put("2", "err");`
```

`

for the above map I want to get all the values associated with the key 1. Expected output.

Key:: 1 values are:: xyz, abc, cde

Order of the values doesn't important.

Comment: If you need to have duplciated key (don't even know a reason why you should), reconsider using another Collection.

Comment: You probably want a multimap - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: First of all you need to understand concepts of HashMap, its internal life. I encourage you to cover [my tutorial](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashmap-in-java.html) where all these things explained !

Answer (score 7):

In a Map the key should always be `unique`. If you associate a new value to an existing key, it will overwrite the value of the existing entry.

You might need to check the interface for [Map#put(K, V)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) method.

> If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value
>   is replaced by the specified value.

So in your case your map will always have `"cde"` as the value for the key `"1"`.

Answer (score 6):

Use MultiMap

```
    MultiMap mapValue = new MultiValueMap();

    mapValue.put("1", "xyz");
    mapValue.put("1", "abc");
    mapValue.put("1", "cde");
    mapValue.put("2", "err");
    System.out.println("Map : " + mapValue);
```

Output:    `Map : {2=[err], 1=[xyz, abc, cde]}`

Answer (score 4):

A map can not have duplicate keys.

If you want to implement what you describe in question. First you need to use [multimaps](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is wrong.

Map doesn't allow duplicates.

So  **one key ----------->  one value**

[If you see docs of put()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)

You can print the values of each `key` and `value` like

```
Ex:

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, a map is called a map because it maps *one* key value to a value. Multiple keys can map to the same value but not the other way around.

What you probably want is a map which maps to a `List<String>` instead:

```
final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

if (map.get("1") == null) {
  map.put("1", new ArrayList<String>());
}

map.get("1").add("xyz");

// ...
```

A helper function for adding might be convenient

```
public static <K, V> void add(final K key, final V value, final Map<K, List<V>> map)
{
    if (map.get(key) == null) {
      map.put(key, new ArrayList<V>());
    }

    map.get(key).add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Map you can't have duplicate keys**. so In your case final value put for key 1. "cde" will remain in Map

You can do some thing like following to achive what you are expecting

```
  Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("xyz");
    list.add("abc");
    list.add("cde");
    list1.add("err");
    map.put("1", list);
    map.put("2",list1);
    System.out.println(map.get("1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with this type of Map. The key in map must be unique.

To be able to do that you should declare a map, where key is string but values are collections of Strings.

`Map<String,Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<String,Collection<String>>();`

The to list values from it you can do this

```
for(String valueOfKey : map.get("key") {
   //print or something else 
}
```

Note that to add some values to it you must first check that key is already stored and if not then fist declare a collection.

```
if(map.contains("key") == false) {
  map.put(new ArrayList<String>());
}

map.get("key").add("value");
```

As this is well know design you might be interest in guava framework and [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

The benefit of this class is that it already has implemented the logic how to add and retrieve values from it.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap::put overrides the old value associated with the key. You have to put a List in each map entry and insert new values in the appropriate list.

Answer (score 0):

From the java documentation about [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).put(K key, V value) method:

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

So you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
for (String k : map.keySet())
    System.out.println(k);
```

This would print the keys in the `HashMap`, but without any guarantees on order.

Answer (score -1):

You can not have duplicate key for a hash map see the below S.O for  [What happens for duplicate keys in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669885/what-happens-when-a-duplicate-key-is-put-into-a-hashmap)