# HashMap allows duplicates?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a doubt regarding HashMap, as we all know HashMap allows one null key and value pair, My question here is

If I wrote like this,

```
m.put(null,null);
m.put(null,a);
```

Will it throw a (error or exception) or will it override the value or what will be the value of returing??

Comment: Why don't you try ?

Comment: Checkout collection API. Null is always a bad choice for a key. So check out what you want to do. In the case of two equal keys the value of the first on will be replaced by the current.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669885/what-happens-when-a-duplicate-key-is-put-into-a-hashmap

Answer (score 36):

Hashmap type Overwrite that key if hashmap key is same key

```
map.put("1","1111");
map.put("1","2222");
```

output

```
key:value
1:2222
```

Answer (score 13):

Each *key* in a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) must be unique.

When "adding a duplicate key" the old value (for the same key, as keys must be unique) is simply replaced; see [HashMap.put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)):

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, *the old value is replaced*.
>
> *Returns the previous value associated with key*, or null if there was no mapping for key.

As far as nulls: a single null *key* is allowed (as keys must be unique) but the HashMap can have any number of null *values*, and a null key need not have a null value. Per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> [.. HashMap] permits null *values* and [a] null *key*.

However, the documentation says *nothing* about null/null needing to be a specific key/value pair or null/"a" being invalid.

Answer (score 12):

Doesn't allow duplicates in the sense, It allow to add you but it does'nt care about this key already have a value or not. So at present for **one key**  there will be only **one value**

It silently overrides the `value` for `null` key. No exception.

When you try  to get, the last inserted value with `null` will be return.

That is not only with `null` and for any key.

Have a quick example

```
   Map m = new HashMap<String, String>();
   m.put("1", "a");
   m.put("1", "b");  //no exception
   System.out.println(m.get("1")); //b
```

Answer (score 9):

Code example:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> h = new HashMap<Integer,String> ();

h.put(null,null);
h.put(null, "a");

System.out.println(h);
```

Output:

```
{null=a}
```

[It overrides the value at key null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29).

Answer (score 3):

HashMap don't allow duplicate keys,but since it's not thread safe,it might occur duplicate keys.
eg:

```
 while (true) {
            final HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>(2);
            map.put("runTimeType", 1);
            map.put("title", 2);
            map.put("params", 3);
            final AtomicInteger invokeCounter = new AtomicInteger();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        map.put("formType", invokeCounter.incrementAndGet());
                    }
                }).start();
            }
            while (invokeCounter.intValue() != 100) {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            if (map.size() > 4) {
// this means you insert two or more formType key to the map
               System.out.println( JSONObject.fromObject(map));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m.put(null,null); // here key=null, value=null
m.put(null,a);    // here also key=null, and value=a
```

Duplicate keys are not allowed in hashmap.
However,value can be duplicated.