# understand Hash map keys- java

Tags: java, hash, dictionary

I know that HashMap doesn’t allow duplicate keys (It does allow duplicate values).
However in this example that works perfectly,all the values have the same key(that means the key is not unique)Maybe I misunderstood the code.Could someone help me understand it right.

this is the code

```
public class PlayListManager {
//**********************************hashmap keys************************
public static final String ALL_VIDEOS = "AllVideos";
public static final String ALL_Songs = "AllSongs";
//***************************************************************************
 ..
 ...
 ....
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Songs song = new Songs();
        song.songId = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
        song.artist = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
        song.title = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
        song.songName = cursor
                .getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
        song.duration = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)));
        song.albumId = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)));
        song.songData = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


        //*******here it uses the same ky for all the videos?!!*************
        HashMap<String, Object> songMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        songMap.put(ALL_Songs, song);
        songsList.add(songMap);

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the output when you try to print out the keys in your map? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V) see this link. You are replacing this key at all times.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669885/what-happens-when-a-duplicate-key-is-put-into-a-hashmap) is an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each iteration of the `while` loop, the code is creating a *new* `HashMap` instance and filling it with only one entry that maps a `String` key (`"AllSongs"`) to the `Song` object.

This map (which contains only one entry) will then be added to the list `songsList`.

After the `while` loop is finished, you would have a list of `HashMap`s where each map basically maps a hardcoded keyword to one song.

> songsList:
>
> <"AllSongs", song1>, <"AllSongs", song2>, <"AllSongs", song3>, ...

In this case, using a `HashMap` seems redundant. You could just fill the list with the `Song` instances without saving each one in a map.

The key concept here is that there are many `HashMap` (each iteration creates one), as opposed to having a "global" `HashMap`. If it were global, each song would overwrite the other since they are always mapped using the same hardcoded key.

Comment: I understand now.But why not use hashmap object to be added to the list Songlist? why not use object Song to be added to the list Songlist instead?---Im talking about this specific example

Comment: You're right: In this case, using a HashMap seems redundant. You could just fill the list with the Song instances without saving each one in a map. But I don't know who wrote this code and why he or she decided on this approach.