# Ignore duplicates when producing map using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Map<String, String> phoneBook = people.stream()
                                      .collect(toMap(Person::getName,
                                                     Person::getAddress));
```

I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key` when a duplicated element is found.

Is it possible to ignore such exception on adding values to the map?

When there is duplicate it simply should continue by ignoring that duplicate key.

Comment: If you can use it, HashSet will ignore the key, if it already exists.

Comment: @captain-aryabhatta. Is it possible to have key values in hashset

Answer (score 664, accepted):

This is possible using the `mergeFunction` parameter of [`Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
Map<String, String> phoneBook = 
    people.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
             Person::getName,
             Person::getAddress,
             (address1, address2) -> {
                 System.out.println("duplicate key found!");
                 return address1;
             }
          ));
```

`mergeFunction` is a function that operates on two values associated with the same key. `adress1` corresponds to the first address that was encountered when collecting elements and `adress2` corresponds to the second address encountered: this lambda just tells to keep the first address and ignores the second.

Comment: I'm confused, why is duplicate **values** (not keys) not allowed? And how to allow duplicate values?

Comment: is there any way to retrieve the key for which the collision occurs ?
answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761954/collectors-tomap-with-same-keysprint-same-key

Comment: Is it possible to totally ignore this entry if there's a clash?  Basically, if I ever encounter duplicate keys I don't want them to be added at all.  In the example above, I don't want address1 or address2 in my map.

Comment: @Hendy Irawan : duplicate values are allowed. The merging function is to chose between (or merge) two values that **have the same key**.

Comment: @djkelly99 Actually you can, you just have to make your remapping function return `null`. 
See [toMap doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) that point to [merge doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) that states _If the remapping function returns null, the mapping is removed._

Comment: Shouldn't we return address2 to mimic standard map behavior.  If this where a for each instead of a collect the standard behavior would be that put on the second address would wipe out the first.  Thus to avoid changes in behavior when code refactoring occurs address2 is the logical choice.

Comment: @Ricola if there are 3 duplicate entries then it will ignore the first two entries but it will pick the third one. I tried with distinct() method to the stream too but same issue.

Comment: @newday I'm not sure I understand what you want. This code will pick the first one. If you *want* to pick the last one return address2 instead.

Comment: @Ricola : it might be that newday meant that returning `null` for the first comparison to skip entry creation still creates one if there's a third with the same key

Comment: @HendyIrawan In a hashmap the index of a value is based on it's key value. In the background there is a hashing function which converts the key into an index. If the same key would be inserted the new value should be placed on the exact same place as the previous value. There are multiple solutions upon resolving this issue, but codewise in the first this is not allowed.

Answer (score 186):

As said in [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-):

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to
> `Object.equals(Object)`), an `IllegalStateException` is thrown when the
> collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys may have
> duplicates, use `toMap(Function keyMapper, Function valueMapper, BinaryOperator mergeFunction)` instead.

So you should use [`toMap(Function keyMapper, Function valueMapper, BinaryOperator mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) instead. Just provide a **merge function**, that will determine which one of duplicates is put in the map.

For example, if you don't care which one, just call

```
Map<String, String> phoneBook = people.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAddress, (a1, a2) -> a1));
```

Comment: This could be a serious data loss if not understood correctly.

Comment: Well, yes. In most cases duplicated values must be somehow combined or exception is thrown (by default and it's correct behavior). But in some rare cases you need to ignore duplicate, and that was the question.

Answer (score 20):

The answer from [alaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1192702/alaster) helped me a lot, but I would like to add  meaningful information if someone is trying to **group** the data.

If you have, for example, two `Orders` with the same `code` but different `quantity` of products for each one, and your desire is to **sum** the quantities, you can do the following:

```
List<Order> listQuantidade = new ArrayList<>();
listOrders.add(new Order("COD_1", 1L));
listOrders.add(new Order("COD_1", 5L));
listOrders.add(new Order("COD_1", 3L));
listOrders.add(new Order("COD_2", 3L));
listOrders.add(new Order("COD_3", 4L));

listOrders.collect(Collectors.toMap(Order::getCode, 
                                    o -> o.getQuantity(), 
                                    (o1, o2) -> o1 + o2));
```

Result:

```
{COD_3=4, COD_2=3, COD_1=9}
```

Or, from the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), you can combine addresses:

```
 Map<String, String> phoneBook
     people.stream().collect(toMap(Person::getName,
                                   Person::getAddress,
                                   (s, a) -> s + ", " + a));
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else getting this issue but without duplicate keys in the map being streamed, **make sure your keyMapper function isn't returning null values**.

It's very annoying to track this down because when it processes the second element, the Exception will say "Duplicate key 1" when 1 is actually the **value** of the entry instead of the key.

In my case, my keyMapper function tried to look up values in a different map, but due to a typo in the strings was returning null values.

```
final Map<String, String> doop = new HashMap<>();
doop.put("a", "1");
doop.put("b", "2");

final Map<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<>();
doop.put("c", "e");
doop.put("d", "f");

doop.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> lookup.get(e.getKey()), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 3):

For grouping by Objects

```
Map<Integer, Data> dataMap = dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getId, data-> data, (data1, data2)-> {LOG.info("Duplicate Group For :" + data2.getId());return data1;}));
```

Comment: How can you log the key name here if the values are strings?

Answer (score 1):

Feels like `toMap` working often but not always is a dark underbelly of the java Streams.  Like they should have called it `toUniqueMap` or something...

The easiest way is to use `Collectors.groupingBy` [instead of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45231743/32453) `Collectors.toMap`.

It will return a `List` type output by default, but collision problem is gone, and that maybe what you want in the presence of multiples anyway.

```
  Map<String, List<Person>> phoneBook = people.stream()
          .collect(groupingBy((x) -> x.name));
```

If  a `Set` type collection of the addresses associated with a particular name, `groupingBy` can do that [as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39882789/32453):

```
Map<String, Set<String>> phoneBook = people.stream()
          .collect(groupingBy((x) -> x.name, mapping((x) -> x.address, toSet())));
```

The other way is to "start" with either a Hash or a Set...And carefully track through to make sure the keys never duplicate in the output stream.  Ugh.  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33606014/32453) that happens to survive this...sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. A map stores key, value pairs and does not allow duplicate keys. If individual objects have duplicate names, you will get the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key

Ex:

```
Map<String, String> stringMap;
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(new Person(1, "Mark", "Menlo Park"));
        personList.add(new Person(2, "Sundar", "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"));
        personList.add(new Person(3, "Sundar", "232 Santa Margarita Ave"));
        personList.add(new Person(4, "Steve", "Los Altos"));

        stringMap = personList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAddress));
```

[image]

To resolve it, we need to use a different method with an additional parameter, the **mergeFunction**.

```
    phoneBook = personList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAddress
                    , (existing, replacement) -> existing));

System.out.println("Map object output :" + stringMap);
```

> Output: **Map object output :{Steve=Los Altos, Mark=Menlo Park, Sundar=1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy}**

NOTE: When you change `(existing, replacement) -> replacement)`. the old key is replaced with the new value.
And if you need all addresses to store the same key check this
[Multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75644186/7950525)

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking get `Map<String, List<Person>>` then follow below steps:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> phoneBook = people
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Person::getName,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (first, second) -> first);
```

**Function.identity():** is a convenient way to indicate that the values in the map should be the Person objects themselves without any modification.

**(first, second) -> first:** This is a merge function used to handle situations where there are duplicate keys in the stream. If two Person objects have the same name (a duplicate key), this function specifies that the value associated with that key should be the first Person encountered (address1) among the duplicates, effectively preserving the first occurrence and discarding the duplicates.

***Use below two case as per you need:***

- If we use `((first, second) -> first)` specifies what to do in case
  of duplicate keys it chooses the first encountered Person.
- If we use `((first, second) -> second)` specifies what to do in case
  of duplicate keys it chooses the last encountered Person.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such a problem when grouping object, i always resolved them by a simple way: perform a custom filter using a java.util.Set to remove duplicate object with whatever attribute of your choice as bellow

```
Set<String> uniqueNames = new HashSet<>();
Map<String, String> phoneBook = people
                  .stream()
                  .filter(person -> person != null && !uniqueNames.add(person.getName()))
                  .collect(toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAddress));
```

Hope this helps anyone having the same problem !

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's how to "reduce" duplicates down to just one.

If you are OK with the last:

```
  Map<String, Person> phoneBook = people.stream()
          .collect(groupingBy(x -> x.name, reducing(null, identity(), (first, last) -> last)));
```

If you want only the first:

```
  Map<String, Person> phoneBook = people.stream()
          .collect(groupingBy(x -> x.name, reducing(null, identity(), (first, last) -> first != null ? first : last)));
```

And if you want last but "address as String" (doesn't use the `identity()` as a parameter).

```
  Map<String, String> phoneBook = people.stream()
          .collect(groupingBy(x -> x.name, reducing(null, x -> x.address, (first, last) -> last)));
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495816/stream-groupingby-reducing-to-first-element-of-list#comment110097397_48123966)

So in essence `groupingBy` paired with a `reducing` collector starts to behave very similarly to the `toMap` collector, having something similar to its mergeFunction...and identical end result...

Answer (score 0):

One can use lambda function: the comparison is done on key string from key(...)

```
List<Blog> blogsNoDuplicates = blogs.stream()
            .collect(toMap(b->key(b), b->b, (b1, b2) -> b1))  // b.getAuthor() <~>key(b) as Key criteria for Duplicate elimination
            .values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

static String key(Blog b){
    return b.getTitle()+b.getAuthor(); // make key as criteria of distinction
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have people is List of object

```
  Map<String, String> phoneBook=people.stream()
                                        .collect(toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAddress));
```

Now you need two steps :

1)

```
people =removeDuplicate(people);
```

2)

```
Map<String, String> phoneBook=people.stream()
                                        .collect(toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAddress));
```

Here is method to remove duplicate

```
public static List removeDuplicate(Collection<Person>  list) {
        if(list ==null || list.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }

        Object removedDuplicateList =
                list.stream()
                     .distinct()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
     return (List) removedDuplicateList;

      }
```

Adding full example here

```
 package com.example.khan.vaquar;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RemovedDuplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person vaquar = new Person(1, "Vaquar", "Khan");
        Person zidan = new Person(2, "Zidan", "Khan");
        Person zerina = new Person(3, "Zerina", "Khan");

        // Add some random persons
        Collection<Person> duplicateList = Arrays.asList(vaquar, zidan, zerina, vaquar, zidan, vaquar);

        //
        System.out.println("Before removed duplicate list" + duplicateList);
        //
        Collection<Person> nonDuplicateList = removeDuplicate(duplicateList);
        //
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("After removed duplicate list" + nonDuplicateList);
        ;

        // 1) solution Working code
        Map<Object, Object> k = nonDuplicateList.stream().distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s1 -> s1.getId(), s1 -> s1));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Result 1 using method_______________________________________________");
        System.out.println("k" + k);
        System.out.println("_____________________________________________________________________");

        // 2) solution using inline distinct()
        Map<Object, Object> k1 = duplicateList.stream().distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s1 -> s1.getId(), s1 -> s1));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Result 2 using inline_______________________________________________");
        System.out.println("k1" + k1);
        System.out.println("_____________________________________________________________________");

        //breacking code
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Throwing exception _______________________________________________");
        Map<Object, Object> k2 = duplicateList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(s1 -> s1.getId(), s1 -> s1));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("k2" + k2);
        System.out.println("_____________________________________________________________________");
    }

    public static List removeDuplicate(Collection<Person> list) {
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        Object removedDuplicateList = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return (List) removedDuplicateList;

    }

}

// Model class
class Person {
    public Person(Integer id, String fname, String lname) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    private Integer id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;

    // Getters and Setters

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", fname=" + fname + ", lname=" + lname + "]";
    }

}
```

Results :

```
Before removed duplicate list[Person [id=1, fname=Vaquar, lname=Khan], Person [id=2, fname=Zidan, lname=Khan], Person [id=3, fname=Zerina, lname=Khan], Person [id=1, fname=Vaquar, lname=Khan], Person [id=2, fname=Zidan, lname=Khan], Person [id=1, fname=Vaquar, lname=Khan]]

After removed duplicate list[Person [id=1, fname=Vaquar, lname=Khan], Person [id=2, fname=Zidan, lname=Khan], Person [id=3, fname=Zerina, lname=Khan]]

Result 1 using method_______________________________________________
k{1=Person [id=1, fname=Vaquar, lname=Khan], 2=Person [id=2, fname=Zidan, lname=Khan], 3=Person [id=3, fname=Zerina, lname=Khan]}
_____________________________________________________________________

Result 2 using inline_______________________________________________
k1{1=Person [id=1, fname=Vaquar, lname=Khan], 2=Person [id=2, fname=Zidan, lname=Khan], 3=Person [id=3, fname=Zerina, lname=Khan]}
_____________________________________________________________________

Throwing exception _______________________________________________
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key Person [id=1, fname=Vaquar, lname=Khan]
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
    at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1253)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.example.khan.vaquar.RemovedDuplicate.main(RemovedDuplicate.java:48)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same case and found that the simplest solution (Assuming you want to just override the map value for duplicate key) is:

```
Map<String, String> phoneBook = 
       people.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, 
                                  Person::getAddress, 
                                        (key1, key2)-> key2));
```

Comment: This is actually a duplicate answer. Please see the accepted one.