# Does parallelStream() in java 8 guarantee the order?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to understand the behavior of `parallelStream()` in java 8. Here is my sample code.

```
List<Person> javaProgrammers = new ArrayList<Person>() {
    {
        add(new Person("Elsdon", "Jaycob", "Java programmer", "male", 43, 2000));
        add(new Person("Tamsen", "Brittany", "Java programmer", "female", 33, 1500));
        add(new Person("Floyd", "Donny", "Java programmer", "male", 33, 1800));
        add(new Person("Sindy", "Jonie", "Java programmer", "female", 32, 1600));
        add(new Person("Vere", "Hervey", "Java programmer", "male", 22, 1200));
        add(new Person("Maude", "Jaimie", "Java programmer", "female", 33, 1900));
        add(new Person("Shawn", "Randall", "Java programmer", "male", 33, 2300));
        add(new Person("Jayden", "Corrina", "Java programmer", "female", 33, 1700));
        add(new Person("Palmer", "Dene", "Java programmer", "male", 33, 2000));
        add(new Person("Addison", "Pam", "Java programmer", "female", 34, 1300));
    }
};

System.out.println("Serial:" + javaProgrammers.stream().filter(person -> person.age == 33).findFirst().toString());
System.out.println("Parallel:" + javaProgrammers.parallelStream().filter(person -> person.age == 33).findFirst().toString());
```

Here I'm comparing `stream()` and `parallelStream()`, and I expect `Brittany Tamsen` to be return always in `stream()` call because that's the first match. But for `parallelStream()` I do not expect `Brittany Tamsen` to be returned **always** because it can be one of any matches, as I expect it to run in parallel.

But the problem is that it also returns `Brittany Tamsen` **always**. So it doesn't look like it runs in parallel.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: note that the double bracket initialization pattern is discouraged, as it creates additional classes.

Comment: My IDE (idea) doesn't complain, though. What is the recommended way? What do you mean by additional classes?

Comment: Found the answer here. https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/
Thanks

Comment: That's a bad heuristic. Just because your IDE doesn't complain about it doesn't mean it's efficient. It's not smarter than you after all.

Comment: And it’s not even shorter than the straight forward solutions, e.g. if you don’t need a resizeable list, use `List<Person> javaProgrammers = Arrays.asList( new Person(…), new Person(…), … );`, it’s shorter *and* more efficient. If you really need a resizable `ArrayList`, you may just pass that list to the `ArrayList`’s constructor or construct an intially empty `ArrayList` and use `Collections.addAll`, in either case, you’re making a small trade-off between brevity and efficiency, but it’s still better than the double curly brace subclassing (and potentially memory leak creation).

Comment: Regarding the actual question, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29218074/2711488) might help.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Bohemian's answer, It's important to add that, yes, `findFirst()` will return the first element matching the predicate, whether the stream is parallel or not, since the stream has an encounter order in this case (being created from a List).

`findAny()`, on the contrary, is free to return any element matching the predicate (and should thus be preferred if you don't really care about which matching element is returned, since it might allow returning sooner in case of a parallel stream).

Answer (score 5):

There is a whole paragraph on ordering in the [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) and another one the interaction between concurrency and ordering further down.

Excerpt (reading the rest is highly recommended):

> Streams may or may not have a defined encounter order. Whether or not
>   a stream has an encounter order depends on the source and the
>   intermediate operations. Certain stream sources (such as List or
>   arrays) are intrinsically ordered

The [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) documentation itself then refers to the encounter order concept defined above.

> Returns an Optional describing the first element of this stream, or an
>   empty Optional if the stream is empty. If the stream has no encounter
>   order, then any element may be returned.

The [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) and [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) docs also describe some behavior relevant to ordering for more complex uses of parallel streams.