# Java 8 Stream groupingby without returning List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to create `Map<Long, String>` directly from a `groupingBy` function in Java 8, instead of creating `Map<Long, Set<String>>`?

I have the following code:

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
//row[0] is the primary key and row[1] is the name of the employee
Object[] input1 = { 1l, "employee1",  null};
Object[] input2 = { 1l, "employee1", "vorw2"};
Object[] input3 = { 2l, "employee2", "vorw3"};
Object[] input4 = { 3l, "employee3", "vorw1"};
list.add(input1);
list.add(input2);
list.add(input3);
list.add(input4);

//code to replaced
Map<String, Set<String>> byPK= list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(row -> row[0].longValue(), Collectors.mapping(row -> row[1].toString(),Collectors.toSet() )));
```

I need the o/p like:

```
List ==> (1l, "employee1" ), (2l,"employee2"), (3l, "employee3").
```

Comment: List has a single generic type. List<Long, String> does not exist. Post code that makes sense, and compiles. Also, please respect the basic Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks for altering me, i replaced the Map by List. edited and corrected the question.

Comment: Still doesn't compile (add() takes a single argument, not 3), and still doesn't respect the naming conventions. Take a step back, open your IDE, write code that compiles in the IDE, and then fix your question.

Comment: Furthermore you need some explicit casts, since you are dealing with `Object[]` arrays, you cannot expect a typed `Map<Long, String>`. Besides from that, I guess you'd better off using the `toMap` collector, with a custom merger that will either return the previous or new value encountered (assuming a same id is always mapped to the same employee value), instead of `groupingBy`.

Comment: I think you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312876/ignore-duplicates-when-producing-map-using-streams

Comment: @AlexisC. It works with me. but don't know how to accept your answer in a comment.

Answer (score 7):

All you need is toMap(), with a merge function which keeps the current employee name (or the new one, since they should be equal):

```
Map<Long , String> employeeNamesById = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(array -> (Long) array[0],
                                  array -> (String) array[1],
                                  (name1, name2) -> name1));
System.out.println("employeeNamesById = " + employeeNamesById);
// prints employeeNamesById = {1=employee1, 2=employee2, 3=employee3}
```