# Java Stream Collectors.toMap value is a Set

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to use a Java Stream to run over a List of POJOs, such as the list `List<A>` below, and transform it into a Map `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

For example, class A is:

```
class A {
    public String name;
    public String property;
}
```

I wrote the code below that collects the values into a map `Map<String, String>`:

```
final List<A> as = new ArrayList<>();
// the list as is populated ...

// works if there are no duplicates for name
final Map<String, String> m = as.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.name, x -> x.property));
```

However, because there might be multiple POJOs with the same `name`, I want the value of the map be a `Set`. All `property` Strings for the same key `name` should go into the same set.

How can this be done?

```
// how do i create a stream such that all properties of the same name get into a set under the key name
final Map<String, Set<String>> m = ???
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) does exactly what you want:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
...
as.stream().collect(groupingBy((x) -> x.name, mapping((x) -> x.property, toSet())));
```

Comment: Small correction, I think it should be import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Comment: You don't need parentheses around a single lambda parameter.

Comment: Horrible Code Style but corret.

Answer (score 7):

@Nevay 's answer is definitely the right way to go by using `groupingBy`, but it is also achievable by `toMap` by adding a [mergeFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) as the third parameter:

```
as.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.name, 
    x -> new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(x.property)), 
    (x,y)->{x.addAll(y);return x;} ));
```

This code maps the array to a Map with a key as `x.name` and a value as `HashSet` with one value as `x.property`. When there is duplicate key/value, the third parameter merger function is then called to merge the two HashSet.

PS. If you use Apache Common library, you can also use their `SetUtils::union` as the merger

Answer (score 3):

Same Same But Different

```
Map<String, Set<String>> m = new HashMap<>();

as.forEach(a -> {
    m.computeIfAbsent(a.name, v -> new HashSet<>())
            .add(a.property);
    });
```

Comment: welcome to the Stackoverflow, i'd like to suggest you to be more descriptive if you want your answer be considered valuable and helpful and get a good feedback

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use the merger function option of the Collectors.toMap function
Collectors.toMap(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction) as follows:

```
final Map<String, String> m = as.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                          x -> x.name, 
                                          x -> x.property,
                                          (property1, property2) -> property1+";"+property2);
```

Comment: Question was about collecting values to Set<String> but not String.