# How to group stringarray to map?

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream, collectors

i'd tried for the last few hours two fix this small problem.
I want to read from a txt file using:

`Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))`

the Input looks like:

```
b -> l;
c -> a;
a -> d;    
c -> l;
```

Now i want to map it like this.

```
{a,=d, b=l, c=[a,l]}
```

I tried to do this with the java stream API:

```
stream.map(x->x.split(" -> ")).collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x[0],
```

x->x[1]));

the Problem is toMap throws an exception if i got duplicate keys.

Is there a way to allow duplicate keys and store the values in a list?.

Comment: (Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39882599/java-stream-collectors-tomap-value-is-a-set) Use groupingBy as Collector.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to use groupingBy with a proper mapping.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> result = list.stream().map(it -> it.split(" -> ")).
  collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t[0], 
   Collectors.mapping(strings -> strings[1], Collectors.toSet())));
```