# Map duplicate keys error fixing using streams in java 8

Tags: java, mapping

I get an `PublicException: Duplicate Keys` error in this place.

```
Map<BgwContract, List<Fee>> bgwContractFeeMap = bgwContractList
            .stream()
            .filter(bgwContract -> !bgwContract.getStatus().equals(BgwContractStatus.CLOSED))
            .filter(bgwContract -> availableIbans.contains(bgwContract.getFeeAccount()))
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(bgwContract -> bgwContract,
                                     bgwContractFeeService::getContractMonthlyFees)
            );
```

I understand that the issue is that there are some duplicates and it immediately crashes. I know that a `.distinct()` would fix this error, but I don't want to lose any data. Is there a way how to **enhance** this mapping to fix this error without loosing any values, maybe some kind of a filter or any other kind of java 8 methods? I'm not talking about MultiMaps etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore duplicates when producing map using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312876/ignore-duplicates-when-producing-map-using-streams)

Comment: @AmitBera I believe that by ignoring the second key(duplicate) it also ignores the value that the second key was mapped to, and I don't want to lose that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a merge function to `Collectors.toMap()`, which handles values having the same key:

```
Map<BgwContract, List<Fee>> bgwContractFeeMap = bgwContractList
            .stream()
            .filter(bgwContract -> !bgwContract.getStatus().equals(BgwContractStatus.CLOSED))
            .filter(bgwContract -> availableIbans.contains(bgwContract.getFeeAccount()))
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                     bgwContractFeeService::getContractMonthlyFees,
                                     (l1,l2)->{
                                         l1.addAll(l2);
                                         return l1;
                                      })
            );
```

In this case, the elements of two value lists having the same key will be concatenated into a single list.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for, just couldn't figure how to google for this solution!

Comment: But now in `l1.addAll(l2);` I get null and it still crashes. Could you please suggest how to deal with that without losing any data?

Comment: @Martin does it mean that `getContractMonthlyFees()` might be returning `null` in some cases? Can you change it to return an empty List instead?

Comment: Could be, I'll try and let you know

Comment: Found the problem, and somehow solved it. the method returned `Collections.singletonList(feeService.getFeeByFeeName(feeName));` I changed it to `List<Fee> feeList = new ArrayList<>();
        feeList.add(feeService.getFeeByFeeName(feeName));
        return feeList;` and the problem dissapeared. I just don't understand why?

Comment: @Martin both `Collections.singletonList()` and `Arrays.asList()` won't do, since both have a fixed length, so you can't add elements to them. You either have to return a mutable `List` from your method, or create a new ArrayList in the merge function.

Comment: @Martin or you can change `bgwContractFeeService::getContractMonthlyFees` to `c -> new ArrayList<>(bgwContractFeeService.getContractMonthlyFees(c))`;

Comment: Oh, so that's why it crashed because it tried to add to `Collections.singletonList()`

Comment: changed to `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(feeService.getFeeByFeeName(feeName)));`

Comment: @Martin I thought `feeService.getFeeByFeeName(feeName)` returns a List (this is implied by the code in your question), so why do you need to wrap it with `Arrays.asList()`? Did you change the method to return an array?