# Using java 8 streams to build a map of map from another map of map

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Map collection in java

```
Map<AreaDate, Map<AreaCategory, List<Location>> dateWiseAreas
```

using java 8 I want to build a map of

```
 Map<Area, Map<AreaCategory, List<Location>> areas
```

**I used the below logic and I get a duplicate key error saying Area key is duplicate**

```
Map<Area, Map<AreaCategory, List<Location>> areas =  dateWiseAreas.entrySet().stream()
.collect(toMap(k -> k.getKey().area(),
               v -> v.getValue()
                     .entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey(), Map::Entry::getValue,
                             (oldValue,newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new))));
```

Java classes

```
Area {
   EUROPE,
   AUSTRALIA,
   ASIA;   
}


AreaDate {
 Area area;
 LocalDate date;
 int priority;
}

AreaCategory {
  NORTH,
  SOUTH,
  WEST,
  EAST;
}

Location {
 int xaxis;
 int yaxis;
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32313148/1400623) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this does help, thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the 3 argument version of `toMap` in the outer collect to avoid conflict on keys where the same area is found multiple times with different dates.

Something like (untested)

```java
Map<Area, Map<AreaCategory, List<Location>> areas =  dateWiseAreas.entrySet().stream()
.collect(toMap(k -> k.getKey().area(),
               v -> v.getValue()
                     .entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey(), Map::Entry::getValue,
                             (oldValue,newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new)),
              (oldValue, newvalue) -> oldValue
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload of `toMap()` which allows you to pass a `BinaryOperator<V>` where `V` in your case is `Map<AreaCategory, List<Location>>`

```java
Map<Area, Map<AreaCategory, List<Location>> areas = dateWiseAreas.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getKey().area(),
        Map.Entry::getValue, // there seems to be no need to copy the whole thing again
        (a, b) -> {
            // merging Map b into Map a
            b.forEach((key, values) -> a.merge(key, values, (c, d) -> {
                // adding all locations from d to a
                c.addAll(d);
                return c;
            });
            return b;
        })
    );
```