# How to explain duplicate entries in Java Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates, multiple-entries

1. This is under multi-threading
2. I have read topics about HashMap and cannot find relevant questions/answers

The code:

```
 private Map<String, String> eventsForThisCategory;
    ...
    Map<String, String> getEventsForThisCategory() {
        if (eventsForThisCategory == null) {
            Collection<INotificationEventsObj> notificationEvents = notificationEventsIndex.getCategoryNotificationEvents(getCategoryId());
            eventsForThisCategory = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(INotificationEventsObj notificationEvent : notificationEvents) {
                eventsForThisCategory.put(notificationEvent.getNotificationEventID(), notificationEvent.getNotificationEventName());
            }
            logger.debug("eventsForThisCategory is {}", eventsForThisCategory);
        }
        return eventsForThisCategory;
    }
```

The output:

> app_debug.9.log.gz:07 Apr 2016 13:47:06,661 DEBUG [WirePushNotificationSyncHandler::WirePushNotification.Worker-1] - eventsForThisCategory is {FX_WIRE_DATA=Key Economic Data, ALL_FX_WIRE=All, ALL_FX_WIRE=All, FX_WIRE_HEADLINES=Critical Headlines}

How is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when a duplicate key is put into a HashMap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669885/what-happens-when-a-duplicate-key-is-put-into-a-hashmap)

Comment: Well, it's not possible. Not for a `HashMap<String, String>` at least. What kind of concurrency does your code have? Is there whitespace that would differ between the two `ALL_FX_WIRE` keys?

Comment: @Kayaman It is multi-threading. There is no whitespace that would differ the 2 keys. As you can see, it prints out the map, and I don't believe it do an auto-trim for String

Comment: @YuriBlanc I will update the question, I already read that topic, have basic understanding of how HashMap work, even know HashMap is not thread safe.

Comment: Well, the only thing that comes to mind is a concurrency issue. I assume you can't replicate the behaviour reliably?

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah, I can't replicate it reliably. I also guess it is concurrency issue, but then how to explain it is difficult. Therefore the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure that your map won't have two equal keys at the same time. What you see is an effect of modifying the map while iterating iver it (in `toString()`). When the second "ALL_FX_WIRE" is written, the first one won't be present in the map any more.

You already know that `HashMap` is not threadsafe. Plus `eventsForThisCategory` can get modified by another thread while `eventsForThisCategory.toString()` is running. So this has to be expected.

Make sure `eventsForThisCategory` is not modified by multiple threads at the same time (or switch to [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)), and make sure it is not modified while `toString()` is running (it is called when you create the debug output).

Comment: Ah right, I totally forgot that a `toString` is also an iteration over the Map.Thanks for the answer,

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is not threadSafety in multi-threading.
you can try to use `Collections.synchronizedMap()` to wrap you hashMap instance
or use the `ConcurrentHashMap` maybe better

Comment: Not the answer I was expecting. You did not explain how it happens.