# Java stream not putting all values of a List into a HashMap

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream

I am working on a program where I need to take a *list* of objects and put them in a `HashMap`, using the *class name* as the *key* and the *instance* as the *value*.

I have the following code:

```
pets2.stream().forEach(pt -> animals.put(pt.getClass().getSimpleName(), pt));
```

Where `pets2` is my *list* of animals is my `HashMap`. However, when I run this and then print the `HashMap`, only two objects from the list have been added into the `Map`.

Not even the first two, just two of them. Any idea as to what the issue is and how I can fix it?

Comment: What type of list is pets2? Or more specifically, what kind of object types can it include?

Comment: Maybe you're putting data with [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669885/what-happens-when-a-duplicate-key-is-put-into-a-hashmap) keys.

Comment: @YaMiN, yes I also suspect the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple instances of the same **class** in a *list*, you will lose information if only a single object will represent a *value* in your *map*.

Instead, you have to group the objects mapped to the same *key* (*i.e. belonging to the same **class***) into a *collection*.

With stream API, you can do it by using the built-in *collector* [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)), which expects a *classifier* function that determines how to extract the *key* from the element of the stream. By default, *values* mapped to the same *key* will be grouped into a *list*.

***Example*** (substitute the type `Object` with your super type):

```
List<Object> pets2 = List.of("foo", 9, "bar", 27, new HashSet<>());

Map<String, List<Object>> classNameToPet =
        pets2.stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> obj.getClass().getSimpleName()));

classNameToPet.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));
```

**Output**

```
Integer : [9, 27]
String : [foo, bar]
HashSet : [[]]
```

***Note*** :

- The way you are using `forEach()` is **not encouraged** by the documentation, [*take a look at the code example provided in the paragraph "side-effects"*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).
- If you need to determine the actual class of your objects in order to interact with them, that means your usage of *inheritance* is wrong. If list `pets2` has a generic parameter let's say `Anymal`, then you don't have to discriminate between the subtypes of `Anymal`, but take advantage from the *polymorphism*.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen, if there are only two different classes in the list. Later objects with the same class as a previous on overwrite the previous one because the key is the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over the pets2 list and adding them to the animals map (Map<String, Object>), the put operation just overwrites the already inserted value for that specific class.

Eg:

```
pets2 = [dog1, dog2, cat1, cat2]
// The final animals map as per your method will be
animals = [{Dog, dog2}, {Cat, cat2}]
```

So, to handle the case of multiple repetitions of the same class objects in the pets list, we can change the code as follows

```
Map<String, List<Object>> animals = new HashMap<>();
pets2.forEach(pet -> animals.computeIfAbsent(pet.getClass().getSimpleName(), p -> new ArrayList<>()).add(pet));
```